# Unlink: Permission Denied - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, arquivo, upload, imagem, delete

Boa tarde pessoal,

Recentemente estive tentando fazer uma gerencia de imagens em que preciso de utilizar o unlink. Segue o código completo da função:

```
$query_listaPic = "SELECT * FROM tbl_imagem WHERE tbl_produto_id = '$id'";
$listaPic = mysql_query($query_listaPic, $techConect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_listaPic = mysql_fetch_assoc($listaPic);
$totalRows_listaPic = mysql_num_rows($listaPic);

chmod("../img/produtos", 0755);
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($listaPic))
{
    unlink('../img/produtos/'.$r->nome);
}

$deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM tbl_imagem WHERE tbl_produto_id = '$id'";

$Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $techConect) or die(mysql_error());


$rand = rand(5,98798967899);

foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
{
    $filename = $rand.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_imagem(nome, tbl_produto_id) VALUE ('$filename', '$id')";

    $dir = "../img/produtos/";
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $dir.$filename);

    $Result2 = mysql_query($query, $techConect) or die(mysql_error());

    //echo "<script> alert('Imagens Atualizadas.'); window.location = 'produto-info.php'; </script>";
}
```

Neste trecho ele deveria selecionar as imagens que ja existem registrados em tal produto, deletar elas e inserir as novas, porém logo em `unlink('../img/produtos/'.$r->nome);` ele me retorna um erro de:

> Unlink: Permission Denied - Trying to get property of non-object

Neste projeto preciso de inserir imagens na pasta 'produtos' url deste arquivo (../img/produtos), e para acessá-las, insiro o nome na tabela tbl_imagem vinculada a tabela tbl_produtos.
Para editar eu faria a exclusão dos registros referentes as imagens e também apagaria os arquivos, e logo apos adicionaria os novos arquivos a pasta e a tabela tbl_imagem.
Para excluir seria somente remover os arquivos e remover os registros do BD.

*Seria algo semelhante a este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjbpyYXqP-A).*

A questão é que não estou conseguindo realizar a edição de imagens do registro, não esta excluindo as imagens antigas e nem inserindo no BD (de acordo com o atual código descrito acima).

Estrutura de Pastas:
Projeto > img > produtos > *imagens*
Projeto > admin > *paginas administrativas*

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_imagem` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
  `tbl_produto_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `fk_tbl_imagem_tbl_produto1_idx` (`tbl_produto_id`)  
);  



CREATE TABLE `tbl_produto` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `descricao` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `codigotm` varchar(11) NOT NULL,  
  `datacadastro` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `tbl_subcategoria_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `fk_tbl_produto_tbl_subcategoria1_idx` (`tbl_subcategoria_id`)  
);
```

Agradeço a todos desde já!

Comment: `fetch_assoc` retorna uma array, e não existe nenhum objeto `$r`.

Comment: @Edilson, vou fazer algumas alterações em relação ao '$r = $Pic'

Comment: @Lucas a estrutura de pastas.

Comment: @rray é o suficiente? não seie exatamente como descrever a estrutura de pastas..

Comment: Ta bom sim, esse arquivo php está dentro de qual pasta?

Comment: @rray pasta admin

Comment: Estes problemas com a função `unlink` estão todos relacionados, ou são por causa da má referência, ou então permissões infuficientes no diretório: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: @Edilson, ja tentei fazer as aletrações de permissões (fiz uma alteração no codigo para voce ver como) e não fez diferença, parece que nada que eu faço muda alguma coisa. O que seria esse problema de má referencia?

Comment: Se o erro continua a ser o `trying to get  property...`, deves proceder como o @rray mencinou a resposta dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($r = $Pic)
{
    unlink('../img/produtos/'.$r->nome);
}
```

`$r` recebe `$Pic`, não seria igual? onde está a condição de parada?

`$Pic = $row_listaPic['nome'];`, `$r` é um array e não um objeto esse é um dos motivos do unklink falhar.

Comment: Entendi.. ok, fiz a mudança e coloquei assim: 'mysql_fetch_object($listaPic)' para que eu possa rodar o array. Certo? Aqui ele continua não apagando as imagens.. @rray

Comment: @Lucas apareceu algum erro?

Comment: não apareceu, porém também não excluiu as imagens @rray

Comment: @lucas é melhor editar o código da pergunta.

Comment: fiz as alterações na linha do while: 'while($r = mysql_fetch_object($listaPic))' @rray

Comment: Coloca na sua pergunta a estrutura do projeto, se puder em texto.

Comment: na verdade estou tentando fazer semelhante a este video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjbpyYXqP-A), vou tentar descrever

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30595/discussion-between-lucas-and-rray).

Comment: @lucas Quando vc imprime `$r->nome` o que aparece? vem o nome do arquivo com extensão? vc deu a permissão correta na pasta?

Comment: ao imprimir aparece '5555076openphotonet_P1000795.JPG' que é o nome de 1 arquivo. Não cheguei a mexer com permissões de pastas ainda, mas ao entrar em propriedades esta liberado para todas alteraçoes para todos os usuários. @rray

Comment: @Lucas, tente passar o caminho completo, não tenho certeza se vai funcionar, `unlink(realpath('../img/produtos/'.$r->nome));`

Comment: Tentei aqui, e não fez diferença o unlink. Estive pensando aqui, será que isso não esta acontecendo devido a versão o PHP? EasyPHP 5.3.0?

Comment: @Lucas, não, veja nas permissões da pasta img, de controle total só para testar, depois vc pode mudar.

Comment: Continua da mesma maneira. Dei permissão total a todos usuários e grupos

Comment: @Lucas, faça `if(!unlink('../img/produtos/'.$r->nome)){ echo 'erro<br>';}`

Comment: Também continua da mesma maneira, não fez diferença nenhuma... :(